# AssertionFailedError: null on boolean method

Tags: java, junit, boolean, assert

I am testing a method that takes two objects as parameters and returns a `boolean`. When I use and `assertTrue` or `assertFalse` on the method in question I get the following test failure: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null`.

I know that I am passing invalid parameters and will likely be causing a [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) within the method but that is not what is happening, instead the test is failing.

Note: I am using `boolean` and not [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).

Sample Code:

Class:

```
public class MyClass{
  public boolean foo(MyObject1 lhs, MyObject2 rhs){
    //doSomething
    //return something
  }
}
```

Test:

```
.... //initilization of myClass, etc.
@Test
public void testFoo(){
  assertTrue(myClass.foo(new MyObject1(), new MyObject2());
}
```

Comment: The error you see is normal if the method `foo` return `false`. That means that it should probably not throw a NPE as your expect. By the way, you are using JUnit 4 (because of the annotation `@Test`) but you still use the the old JUnit 3 `Assert` class (of package junit.framework).

Comment: I think you did not encounter a nullpointer inside, you can test this by running the method outside of the asserTrue. Let me know the result.

Comment: The `null` is the message you didn't give to the `assertTrue` method. http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)

Comment: @LaurentG. is there a new Assert class? What is the difference?

Comment: @Vegard I attempted to store the result in a temporary variable and did not recieve my expected NPE, however both assertTrue & assertFalse still fail.

Comment: @Brian Ususally when I use an assert without a message parameter, it does not print anything for the message. Instead this is printing "null"

Comment: Without the actual method under test and the stack trace ... hard to tell you more than that. The only thing I know that would cause that assertion to fail outside of the conditional true/false is if something else inside it is throwing an exception up the stack that isn't being caught or if a `null` Boolean were to be returned (though I actually don't remember what that would do re: autounboxing or if the compiler would yell at you).

Comment: Unbelievable.. assertTrue is working now..

Comment: @AnthonyW They simply changed the package names since JUnit 4. Both classes are similar. The old junit.framework classes are deprecated in the latest version of JUnit.

Comment: @LaurentG. I did some digging and my test class is extending a class that extends the JUnit 3 test class. That is what is causing my asserts to display "null" as they were implemented differently between JUnit 3 & 4. Can you pop up an answer highlighting that asserts in 3 & 4 have different default message so I can check this off?

Comment: Part of the problem is Eclipse turned off the autosave of dirty files so when I changed the asserts around, I still saw the same messge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"`null`" shows up as the message in a JUnit 3 assert ([`junit.framework.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/junit/framework/Assert.html)) with a blank message parameter. This has been fixed in JUnit 4 ([`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html)).

**Example:**

*JUnit 3:*

`assertTrue(false)` has the same stack trace as `assertTrue("null", false)`

*JUnit 4:*

`assertTrue(false)` has the same stack trace as `assertTrue("", false)`