# Jenkins using the wrong JUnit version

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

One of my tests (which was working fine for a few weeks) started failing with a JUnit v3.x error code:

```
  [junit] Testcase: testState took 1.079 sec
    [junit]     FAILED
    [junit] null
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    [junit]     at com.test.PanelTest.testState(PanelTest.java:331)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

There are no references to `junit.framework` anywhere. I am using `import org.junit.*` for all tests (except the deprecated ones which are not being tested on Jenkins).

EDIT: Removed all `junit.framework` imports from deprecated tests.

I suspect that Jenkins is sometimes still using JUnit 3.x, when it should be using only JUnit 4.x. I have searched everywhere for the existence of other JUnit versions and there only remain the jar files for JUnit 4.11.

No matter what I change in my test code, this error won't go away. I've also tried "wiping" the workspace and verifying that the ant scripts do not have any references to Junit 3.x.

Here is my ANT plugin configuration:

[image]

Here is a stripped down version of my Unit Test:

```
package com.test;

import org.fest.swing.core.GenericTypeMatcher;
import org.fest.swing.edt.FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager;
import org.fest.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner;
import org.fest.swing.edt.GuiQuery;
import org.fest.swing.edt.GuiTask;
import org.fest.swing.fixture.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SomeFinalClass.class })
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.swing.*")
public class PanelTest {

    private FrameFixture frameFixture = null;
    private MyPanel panel = null;
    private MyModel model = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void runOnce() {
        FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        <TestFrame extends JFrame>
        TestFrame testFrame = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<TestFrame>() {
            @Override
            protected TestFrame executeInEDT() throws Throwable {

                <lots of mocking and stubbing>

                return new TestFrame(panel);
            }
        });

        GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiTask() {
            @Override
            protected void executeInEDT() throws Throwable {
                SwingUtils.setLookAndFeel();
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(panel);
            }
        });

        frameFixture = new FrameFixture(testFrame);
        frameFixture.show();
        frameFixture.robot.waitForIdle();
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        frameFixture.cleanUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testState() {

        AnotherPanel otherPanel = myModel.getOtherPanel();

        Assert.assertFalse(otherPanel.isShowing());

        <create fake data>
        myModel.update(fakeData);

        JButtonFixture button = <get button Fixture>
        button.click();

        Assert.assertTrue(otherPanel.isShowing());

        button.click();

        Assert.assertFalse(otherPanel.isShowing());  <-- here is where it fails
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run your tests on Jenkins? Via Maven?

Comment: No Maven, just calling ANT.

Comment: Have you installed the plugin for ANT in jenkin and if yes and have you given in config Build as "Invoke ANT"

Comment: Yes and yes (screenshot added).

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use JMockit (http://jmockit.org/) rather than Mockito and Powermock in tandem. If it were me, I'd certainly run the experiment where I replace Mockito and Powermock with JMockit just to see if I'd have yet another reason to prefer JMockit. Just a thought, because I know that desperate times call for desperate measures. Also, I'm a big fan of AssertJ (http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/).

Comment: Does it also fail if you write?
``Assert.assertFalse(false);``

Comment: @unigeek - I am working on your solution, my test is unfortunately a lot longer than the abbreviated version.

Comment: @JSONStatham - No.

Answer (score 1):

`AssertionFailedError` still exists on JUnit 4 and is used by deprecated class `junit.framework.Assert`.

Instead of using `junit.framework.Assert` on `PanelTest` class, use `org.junit.Assert`. Verify the imports.

Comment: There are no references to `junit.framework` anywhere except in some old deprecated tests which are not being run on Jenkins. All of my tests, including the one that is failing, are using `import org.junit.*`

Comment: any test(your old deprecated tests) dependencies are downloaded prior to the execution i.e during compilation. In which case you might be ending up with a previous version download as well. Just try using the `Ver 4.x` in all.

Comment: Please show us full stack trace (maybe there is a cause exception) and PanelTest code.

Comment: Stack trace was already complete, but I updated with the RAW output from Jenkins. I also added a stripped down version of the test case

Comment: I updated all deprecated tests to remove any junit.framework imports, unfortunately the results are identical.

Answer (score 0):

### From your error log,

```
  [junit] Testcase: testState took 1.079 sec
    [junit]     FAILED
    [junit] null
    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    [junit]     at com.test.PanelTest.testState(PanelTest.java:331)
```

So your error is happened in **line no 331** of `PanelTest.java`.

---

if the below line is 331,

```
Assert.assertFalse(otherPanel.isShowing());  // here is where it fails
```

So, from your log, `otherPanel` is null here. `otherPanel` is read/produced from `myModel.getOtherPanel();`.
so for this case, you can use sleep after clicking `btnExpandInfo.click();`. Sometimes it may take time to load and the related otherPanel is not read on that case.

```
btnExpandInfo.click();
Thread.sleep(5000); // if fails, you can try for 30000ms or more
Assert.assertFalse(otherPanel.isShowing());
```

---

### Issue for `btnExpandInfo.click();`

I have not get any info about `btnExpandInfo`. You have not declared or called to prepare this object. So, it also may be null if this button is not found to be clickable.

---

### JUnit Version Issue:

"null" shows up as the message in a `JUnit 3` assert ([`junit.framework.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/junit/framework/Assert.html)) with a blank message parameter. This has been fixed in `JUnit 4` ([`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html)).

Example:

**JUnit 3:**

`assertTrue(false)` has the same stack trace as `assertTrue("null", false)`

**JUnit 4:**

`assertTrue(false)` has the same stack trace as `assertTrue("", false)`

Credit goes to @[AnthonyW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173731/anthonyw)

### Resource Link:

1. [AssertionFailedError: null on boolean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112757/assertionfailederror-null-on-boolean-method)

Comment: I have tried many variations of "waiting" as you suggested after clicking and more recently I used while(otherPanel.isShowing()) with a Thread.sleep(1000) and the test times out (30s) waiting for the otherPanel i.e. otherPanel is never null. True btnExpandInfo is null in my example code, but I assure you it is not null - it is a valid JButtonFixture.
I'm not sure what you are trying to say about the "null" message... are you saying I have JUnit v3 installed?

Comment: @glenneroo you can check it by using Thread.sleep(90000) for loading other panel. as you are assuring it comes, so it will execute well.

Comment: I put the Thread.sleep(1000) into a while loop for 60 minutes(!!) and the test still fails. The test works fine on multiple PCs, only on my Jenkins build does it have this problem, which is why I think this is a Jenkins failure and not my code.

Comment: @glenneroo So on that case, you can compare configuration with another pc. Then you can find what is the difference and can solve.

Comment: I think you misunderstand - it works OK on ALL PCs (Windows/Linux using Intellij IDEA). It does NOT work on Jenkins (running on Linux). Do you know what Jenkins is?

Comment: yap. I know jenkins.

Comment: So then you understand that I have nothing to compare since this test case is only not working on Jenkins.

Comment: @glenneroo would you please share the full log of your jenkins log.

Comment: Please follow this tutorial for again setting junit in jenkins http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_unit_testing.htm

Comment: Unfortunately it has ~10,000 lines because of many other tests. The very first comment of my question has the relevant part of the raw Jenkins output included. Everything else in the log file is unnecessary to show (and contains possibly sensitive information which I can not release).

Comment: on that case, you can run from any of your branch or dev instead of trunk for checking purpose.

Comment: Thank you, but our Jenkins server is otherwise working fine since at least one year. ~700 other unit tests are running every day without any issues, it is only this one test which is throwing this JUnit V3 exception, even though the test is JUnit V4.

Comment: For your concern, I want to suggest you can use Assert.assertEquals(..) instead of Assert.assertFalse(...) for this specific test case and have a try.

Comment: Here is the log output: "expected:<false> but was:<true>". p.s. Thanks for your patience and for continuing to try to help!

Comment: So, the method is giving true. So you can work on that area. Hope now you can solve your issue. :) Thanks for sharing.